# Make a web looks like a book

Tags: javascript, html, css

**Hello friends from SO:**

I come with a very simple question today: we're trying to make a webpage, or, to be even more clear, an html document, look like a book!

**Ok, what do you mean?**

I want the elements to go down, until it reaches the maximum height of the screen, let's say, 800px, and then jump to the right.

**So let's say an example:**

We have a div with a total height of 300px, then, down there comes the second div, with another 300px, and then the third one, but hey! the visible area of the screen, has only 900x of height, so the 3rd div should actually go to the right, instead of making the scroll bar appear.

**So anyone has an idea how this can be done using CSS3 and HTML5?** I'd rather **avoid Js,** but if there's no other option, it will be more than welcome.

**Thanks in advance and happy new year!
Chris;**

---

For anyone coming here with the same problem, I found several solutions by now:

- http://css-tricks.com/how-to-create-a-horizontally-scrolling-site/
- [How to make horizontal scroll on page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13379053/how-to-make-horizontal-scroll-on-page)
- http://hotdot.pro/en/
- http://www.bartleboglehegarty.com/

**Kind regards;
Chris;**

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results.

Comment: I didn't attemp any solution at all, I'm reading the documentation in order to do something like this, I don't know why it didn't work, and I'm wondering if you actually read my question... Thanks however.

Comment: @ChrisRusso LOLLZZZZ exactly.

Comment: @ChrisRusso Yes, I read your question and saw nothing that indicated you have made any attempts at this. SO is not a site where you ask for code, but rather where you ask why the code you have is not working.

Comment: I didn't see him asking for code? Just guidance on approaches?

Comment: @steve this is turning into quite the not-getting-it-fest. "I didn't attempt any solution at all" is a 100% guaranteed sign that the question is inappropriate for SO. Dryden's comment is right from the SO guidelines.

Comment: @steve I guess he didn't directly ask for code, but he also didn't provide any. I'll admit I jumped to a conclusion on this, but either way, he admitted to not making any attempts himself so far, which tends to not sit well here at SO.

Comment: @m59 Perhaps some more charity is advisable if you want to write this on your SO profile: "We love Jesus who is our King, Savior, and Friend. We love people." :)

Comment: @Nick I certainly do. When was I uncharitable?

Comment: @m59 fair enough - I'm obviously in a good mood :)

Comment: @Nick policing SO is a noble thing, and the only way to keep a high quality Q&A site. Chris is very welcome to attempt to solve this himself first and come back for advice.

Comment: @m59 It seems to me that whilst your critique of the appropriateness of the question is valid, phrases like "LOLLZZZZ exactly" and "quite the not-getting-it-fest" are less gracious and considerate of others' feelings than would be ideal :)

Comment: @Nick I think if a person's feelings are that attached to a Stack Overflow post - they really need some friends and they're welcome to come over for dinner anytime and I'd be glad to be one and whatever else they need. Nonetheless, my apologies to you if I offended you. I did admit in that very same post that I'm critical of code (also...illogical things in general).

Comment: @m59 It's all good. I wasn't offended. Just iron sharpening iron :)

Comment: @Nick I can accept that =D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Text flowing between columns has long been a limitation / pain the in the backside for web developers.

CSS3 allows some solutions - which have variable browser support.

This is an old article - but have a read for an idea of one approach: http://alistapart.com/article/css3multicolumn

And a more recent update on the CSS3 options:
http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2013/03/how-to-use-css3-columns/

Some javascript will likely be needed to handle the movement to the right / transitions beyond the visible screen though.